# Anchors direct to an ID but keeping page position

Tags: javascript, anchor

I have a problem with a group of anchors that I want to show in some kind of viewer.

I'm trying to build a word glossary which depends on 2 columns, one will work as a word container and the other one will show the meaning of the word.

I have found a solution that keeps the position of screen on chrome and safari, but its not working on firefox and also don't think is the ideal solution. 
here's a little bit of my code:

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  }

.word{
  width: 50%;
}

.meaning{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.meaning p{
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="word">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#meaning-1">word 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meaning-2">word 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meaning-3">word 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meaning-4">word 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meaning-5">word 5</a></li>
     </ul>   
  </div>
  <div class="meaning">
      <div id="meaning-1">
        <p>1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tortor  vitae              leo ultrices pharetra. Nulla accumsan quis nulla accumsan sollicitudin. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="meaning-2">
        <p>2- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tortor vitae              leo ultrices pharetra. Nulla accumsan quis nulla accumsan sollicitudin. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="meaning-3">
        <p>3- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tortor vitae              leo ultrices pharetra. Nulla accumsan quis nulla accumsan sollicitudin. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="meaning-4">
        <p>4- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tortor vitae              leo ultrices pharetra. Nulla accumsan quis nulla accumsan sollicitudin. </p>
      </div>
      <div id="meaning-5">
        <p>5- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor tortor vitae              leo ultrices pharetra. Nulla accumsan quis nulla accumsan sollicitudin. </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main problem is that whenever I click on words all the page goes up and I want to prevent this to happen.

Is there anyway to avoid the anchors move the screen and only reach the ID's?

How do my html looks like:

[image]

This how it looks like when the position its changed:

[image]

Comment: So you dont want it go up to the page but stay at the current scroll position?

Comment: You really need to make a fiddle of this...